# Upload an Image to multiple facebook accounts in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, access-token

I have a Facebook application that the users can subscribe in it. To subscribe, I made a PHP webpage that the user can log in using his Facebook account information and when he become logged in **I store the user id and the access token to my MySQL DB.** And then I get all the access tokens as an XML file to my application.

Now, I want to publish statuses and photos to the subscribed users accounts. But when I want to upload a photo to the accounts, I must upload the photo to each account in each posting operation and this method is useless.

My posting code is as follow:

```
public static bool PostImage(string ImageDesc, string ImagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string accesstoken = "";

            if (ImagePath.Length < 0)
                return false;

            int progressMaxValue = Controller.participants.Descendants("participant").Count();
            int increment = 100 / progressMaxValue;

            PostImageCPanel.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            foreach (XElement xe in Controller.participants.Descendants("participant"))
            {
                try
                {
                    accesstoken = xe.Attribute("access_token").Value;

                    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken); 
                    var imageStream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);


                    dynamic res = client.Post("/me/photos", new
                    {
                        message = (ImageDesc"),
                        file = new FacebookMediaStream
                        {
                            ContentType = "image/jpg",
                            FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
                        }.SetValue(imageStream)

                    });
                    PostImageCPanel.progressBar1.Value += increment;
                }
                catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex);
                }                     
            }
```

So, I am asking if I can **upload the photo to MySQL DB for just once and then post it to the participants Facebook accounts** instead of uploading it each time for each account. **Or another method to publish the photo quicker.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , i just have tested it 2 days before and works fine for me with CronJobs.
and for you this also will take some time , because every time you publish the photo the facebook uploaded it again.

Comment: Mr. Islam, Actually I followed your videos to post on my Facebook wall, and they were great lessons, but I want to publish for many people in one click and I don't want to upload the photo to each participant account. I do not know what is CronJobs!

Comment: thanks for your words,But you are missing understand something i will give you an approach : first add all post details to you database i assume you have table called `posts`-upload the image on the server and save the FileName only in the table- then you must have another table called `users` which contains the users id,access_tokens. and from whatever your application desktop or webpage make a loop on the users and publish what you need from posts. hope you got the idea ! if then don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for your concert. I hope that you publish the remaining videos of your series.

But how can I post  the photo to each profile in code??
I'm using C# SDK, I think that the parameters that I can pass are: message, source, picture, etc.. 

And if you have the code to upload the photo to MySQL server it will be very useful for me since I tried many codes that are available on the internet and they are useless